# Drush says my module is not found

Tags: bash, drupal, drupal-7, drush

I have two drupal sub-site installations on my development system.  One is a copy of production site with many modules and it is where I am doing my development.  I have a clean Drupal sub-site install where I am testing installing the modules individually to make sure the installers are written correctly.  I wrote a bash script to remove the module from the test site and reinstall an updated copy from the dev site.  Here is the psudo code for the script.

```
cd /path/to/drupalsite/sites/testsite/modules

// clear stuff
drush cc all
drush pm-refresh

// remove myModule
drush dis myModule -y
drush pmu myModule -y
rm -r myModule

// copy from dev
cp /moduledir/from/dev/site/myModule myModule

// clear again for good measure
drush cc all
drush pm-refresh

// re-enable myModule
drush en myModule
```

The module directory is successfully copied but Drush says:

```
myModule was not found.                                       [warning]
No release history was found for the requested project        [error]
(myModule)
```

I can see the myModule module in my Drupal when viewing the module list.  But Drush cannot see it.  I have even run the drush commands manually in the shell with the same results.

Any advice?  I need a way to quickly reinstall this module so I can test the installer.  I know that `drush devel-reinstall myModule` exists but I am changing schema as I go and am updating the .installer and .module files a lot.

Comment: maybe "drush cc drush"

Comment: Does the module appear in modules list `?q=admin/modules`?

Comment: @Muhammad yes it does

Comment: Can you enable the module from this page? What is the exact module name? Also make sure `module.info` file has all required info

Comment: @MuhammadReda, I can enable it from the UI. The name of the module is 'ecuse_application'.

Comment: I finally gave up and installed a clean Drupal instance and altered the script to copy the modules into sites/all/modules/custom and it works now.  I think the issue is the multi-site vs single-site configuration.  Something in the multi-site configuration is confusing drush.

Comment: @ScottAnderson wouldn't `drush cc all` handle `drush cc drush`?

Comment: No, they are different. drush cc all handles all the site caches but doesn't clear the drush cache. I had the same issue this week after using drush cc all but then after drush cc drush the module was found.